# How to use XSL to extract metadata like title and description from html

Tags: html, xslt, xpath

I am a newbie in XSL. I would like to extract two values(title and description) from my HTML. This is how my HTML looks like

```
...
    tbody id="_tableBody">
    <tr id="tcm:526-94999" class="alt-rowcolor" style="display: table-row;">
    <th class="heading" scope="row" style="display: table-cell;">
    <a onclick="displayAgreementPDFPopIn('202', 'ddctable-526-93813', 'Link_1382596320857', '540', 'false')" href="javascript:void(0)">529 Plan – Investment Instructions</a>
    </th>
    <td class="description" style="display: table-cell;">Change how your future contributions are invested or make an exchange of the contributions and earnings currently invested in your 529 college savings plan.</td>
    </tr>
...
```

For eg, I want

```
<title> 529 Plan – Investment Instructions</title>
<description> Change how your future contributions are invested or make an exchange of the contributions and earnings currently invested in your 529 college savings plan </description>
```

This is the XPATH of the element:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/table/tbody/
```

I have all the other title and description under this path. I've created the below XSL for this transformation.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/table/tbody" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="tbody">
  <xsl:call-template name="PDF_metadata">
        </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="PDF_metadata">
  <xsl:variable name="title" select="/tr/th/a">
  <xsl:variable name="description" select="/tr/th/td"/>
   <xsl:attribute name="title">
      <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="description">
      <xsl:value-of select="$description" />
</xsl:template>
```

Is this the right way of using the XSL? Am I doing this right? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've complicated your last template too much.  Untested, but I think this is closer to what you want:

```
<xsl:template name="PDF_metadata">
  <title>
     <xsl:value-of select="tr/th/a" />
  </title>
  <description>
     <xsl:value-of select="tr/td" />
  </description>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Update**

Played around with an online XSLT tester.  This should work for you; it replaces all 3 templates with one simple one.

```
<xsl:template match="//tbody[@id='_tableBody']">
  <title>
   <xsl:value-of select="tr/th/a" />
  </title>
  <description>
   <xsl:value-of select="tr/td" />
  </description>
</xsl:template>
```

Explanation:

`//tbody` finds any `<tbody/>` nodes below the root node.  Doesn't matter how deeply it is nested, or what position it is in inside `<div/>` tags, etc.  But there can be more than one of those, so ...

`//tbody[@id='_tableBody']` ... only match the `<tbody/>` with an attribute `id='_tableBody'`.  Since `id` attributes must be unique, there can only be one.

In the `<xsl:value-of select="..." />`, we are already at the `<tbody/>` node.  To get the title, we don't want to search from the root of the document with `/tr/th/a` ... just from the current node (the `<tbody/>` node), using `tr/th/a` (note the missing `/` at the start).  Ditto for the description.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a large html file which has many tr and td tags. I think I have to specify this entire path /html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/table/tbody/ to get to that element. What do you think?

Comment: @NupurJaiswal  Updated.  Since your `tbody` tag has an `id` attribute, the search for the tag can be greatly simplified from `/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/table/tbody` to `//tbody[@id='_tableBody']`

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I will check this answer